# Rails 4: m/d/yy will not successfully format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, date-formatting

I am pretty familiar with `strptime` in Rails, but I cannot get this date to format.  The date is coming from a long .csv file so it would be a pain to pre-format the dates differently.

```
date = "2/9/17"
Date.strptime(date, "%-m/%-d/%y")

ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `strptime` documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime):

> strptime does not support specification of flags and width unlike strftime

So you need a slightly simplified pattern:

```
date = "2/9/17"
Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y")
# => #<Date: 2017-02-09 ((2457794j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y")`?